# Split a number into three buckets with constraints

Tags: algorithm, probability, combinatorics

Is there a good algorithm to split a randomly generated number into three buckets, each with constraints as to how much of the total they may contain.

For example, say my randomly generated number is 1,000 and I need to split it into buckets a, b, and c.

```
These ranges are only an example. See my edit for possible ranges.
Bucket a may only be between 10% - 70% of the number (100 - 700)
Bucket b may only be between 10% - 50% of the number (100 - 500)
Bucket c may only be between 5% - 25% of the number (50 - 250)
a + b + c must equal the randomly generated number
```

You want the amounts assigned to be completely random so there's just as equal a chance of bucket a hitting its max as bucket c in addition to as equal a chance of all three buckets being around their percentage mean.

EDIT: The following will most likely always be true: low end of a + b + c < 100%, high end of a + b + c > 100%. These percentages are only to indicate acceptable values of a, b, and c. In a case where a is 10% while b and c are their max (50% and 25% respectively) the numbers would have to be reassigned since the total would not equal 100%. This is the exact case I'm trying to avoid by finding a way to assign these numbers in one pass.

I'd like to find a way to pick these number randomly within their range in one pass.

Comment: If we select the 10% of the first bucket then the max number we can get is (10%+50%+25%)*x = 85% of the initial number. So a+b+c cannot hold.

Comment: Sorry this wasn't clear. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: Yes, you're right, the result is not uniformly distributed.

Let's say your percent values are natural numbers (if this assumption is wrong, you don't have to read further :) In that case I don't have a solution).

Let's define an event `e` as a tuple of 3 values (percentage of each bucket): e = (p<sub>a</sub>, p<sub>b</sub>, p<sub>c</sub>). Next, create all possible events e<sub>n</sub>. What you have here is a tuple space consisting of a discrete number of events. All of the possible events should have the same possibility to occur.

Let's say we have a function f(n) => e<sub>n</sub>. Then, all we have to do is take a random number n and return e<sub>n</sub> in a single pass.

Now, the problem remains to create such a function `f` :)

In pseudo code, a very slow method (just for illustration):

```
function f(n) {
    int c = 0
    for i in [10..70] {
        for j in [10..50] {
            for k in [5..25] {
                if(i + j + k == 100) {
                    if(n == c) {
                        return (i, j, k) // found event!
                    } else {
                        c = c + 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What you have know is a single pass solution, but problem is only moved away. The function f is very slow. But you can do better: I think you can calculate everything a bit faster if you set your ranges correctly and calculate offsets instead of iterating through your ranges.

Is this clear enough?

---

First of all you probably have to adjust your ranges. 10% in bucket `a` is not possible, since you can't get condition `a+b+c = number` to hold.

Concerning your question: (1) Pick a random number for bucket `a` inside your range, then (2) update the range for bucket `b` with minimum and maximum percentage (you should only narrow the range). Then (3) pick a random number for bucket `b`. In the end `c` should be calculated that your condition holds (4).

Example:

```
    n = 1000
(1) a = 40%
(2) range b [35,50], because 40+35+25 = 100%
(3) b = 45%
(4) c = 100-40-45 = 15%
```

Or:

```
    n = 1000
(1) a = 70%
(2) range b [10,25], because 70+25+5 = 100%
(3) b = 20%
(4) c = 100-70-20 = 10%
```

It is to check whether all the events are uniformly distributed. If that should be a problem you might want to randomize the range update in step 2.

Comment: I've updated the question to address the possibility and problem of a being 10%.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is equivalent to selecting a random point in an N-dimensional object (in your example N=3), the object being defined by the equations (in your example):

```
0.1  <= x  <= 0.7
0.1  <= y  <= 0.5
0.05 <= z  <= 0.25
x + y + z   = 1 (*)
```

Clearly because of the last equation (*) one of the coordinates is redundant, i.e. picking values for x and y dictates z.

Eliminating (*) and one of the other equations leaves us with an (N-1)-dimensional box, e.g.

```
0.1 <= x  <= 0.7
0.1 <= y  <= 0.5
```

that is cut by the inequality

```
0.05 <= (1 - x - y) <= 0.25 (**)
```

that derives from (*) and the equation for z. This is basically a diagonal stripe through the box.

In order for the results to be uniform, I would just repeatedly sample the (N-1)-dimensional box, and accept the first sampled point that fulfills (**). Single-pass solutions might end up having biased distributions.

Comment: The problem with this is if x and y are both 0.1. It would mean that z must be 0.8 which is outside of its acceptable bounds.